# Getting access denied error on uploading the file to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-java-sdk

Getting access denied error:

> Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: AEB65D41FEB958C7; S3 Extended Request ID: jhCxO/Mv4MTxMRjvkM3bHVJ3dhb7TBeK0k7qHFUY3Q/RFhF591mRLeIzPXUEF0EdtgX9FNJXSq4=), S3 Extended Request ID: jhCxO/Mv4MTxMRjvkM3bHVJ3dhb7TBeK0k7qHFUY3Q/RFhF591mRLeIzPXUEF0EdtgX9FNJXSq4=File Upload Exception:Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: AEB65D41FEB958C7;

when trying to upload the file. My code is:

```
private void uploadFile(String fileName, File file) {
    System.out.print("clouldfileservice: putREqeust");
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(this.bucketName, fileName, file)
            .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
    try {
        PutObjectResult result = this.s3Client.putObject(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("File Upload Exception:" + e.toString());
        System.out.print("File Upload Exception:" + e.getLocalizedMessage());

    }

}
```

Comment: You are receiving an `Access Denied` error. What makes you think that your code should be permitted to `PutObject` into that bucket? What policies are associated with the AWS credentials being used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error indicates that you don't have an access to S3 Bucket.

**Proper solution:**

Go to [policy generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) and generate one, it's a configuration that defines who has access to this resource.

Paste that policy to **Bucket settings** > **permissions** > **Bucket Policy** and save.

**Quick & dirty solution:**

Check "list" and "write" checkboxes in: **Bucket settings** > **Permissions** > **Public Access** > **Everyone**.

Go to: **Bucket settings** > **permissions** > **Bucket Policy**

Answer (score 1):

Correct solution is to remove `withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);` from `PutObjectRequest` object. You are trying to set the optional pre-configured access control policy to use for the new object but your bucket has private access.